# Blender to json for webGL

Tags: json, three.js, blender

right now I'm trying to just take a simple blender 3d image and turn it into a json file. There are lots of guides on how to do it with three.js, but every single one of them seems to refer to a piece of code that no longer exists, specifically this one : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender. Any idea how to do it without this? I'm pretty lost right now. New to Blender and three.js so please just let me know if there's any critical information I'm leaving out.

Comment: The Three.js docs have an article dedicated to this: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models and they recommend you use https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter

Answer (score 2):

The Blender JSON exporter was removed with `R93`. The recommended 3D format of `three.js` is now `glTF`. The following guide should provide all relevant information in order to start with `glTF`.

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models

`three.js R99`